# Angular js directive using controller as syntax ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am having trouble getting a click event in a directive with an isolated scope to work using "controller as" syntax in Angular 1.3 the code for the directive is as follows:

```
myDirectives.directive('gsphotosquare', dirfxn);

function dirfxn() {
    var directive = {
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            photoInfo: '=',
            photoBatchNum: '=',
            thumbnailwidth: '='
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        controller: Ctrller,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        template: '<div ng-click="ctrl.squareClicked()">test</div>',
        //templateUrl: 'views/directives/gsphotosquare.html',
        bindToController: true, // because the scope is isolated
        link: linkFunc //adding this didn't help
    };
    return directive;
}

function Ctrller() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.squareClicked = function () {
        alert('inside clickhandler for gsphotosquare directive');
    };
}

function linkFunc(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {

    el.bind('click', function () {
        alert('inside clickhandler for gsphotosquare directive');
    });
}
```

And here is how the directive is used in the DOM:

```
 <span class="input-label">General Site Photos</span>
    <div class=" item row">
    <gsphotosquare photo-info="mt.photos.v1f1[0]" photo-batch-num="mt.photoBatchNum" ></gsphotosquare>
    <gsphotosquare photo-info="mt.photos.v1f1[1]" photo-batch-num="mt.photoBatchNum" ></gsphotosquare>
    <gsphotosquare photo-info="mt.photos.v1f1[2]" photo-batch-num="mt.photoBatchNum" ></gsphotosquare>
   <gsphotosquare photo-info="mt.photos.v1f1[3]" photo-batch-num="mt.photoBatchNum" ></gsphotosquare>
</div>
```

Any ideas why clicking on the rendered directive doesn't show the alert?

Comment: works fine here  http://plnkr.co/edit/76zYMXB1bTWsIVncJhkR?p=preview

Comment: charlietfl, thanks for you comment, that got me looking in the right direction. Apparently I had it buried deep in a form and had wrapped it with a label element (using ionic). Simply removing the directive from the label element. If you can reproduce your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your controller a little differently:

```
myDirectives.controller('Ctrller', Ctrller);
```

then in your directive:

```
controller: 'Ctrller as ctrl',
```